# Access Google Analytics API with OAuth credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-api

I am attempting to use the [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) from a node project

The API is accessed using the [BetaAnalyticsDataClient](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/analytics-data/latest/v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.html)

I can find examples of using the client with a service account but not with OAuth credentials.
There is a workaround [detailed here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-analytics-data/issues/41) but I am wondering if there isn't some simple way Google supports access to this API using OAuth credentials they have issued specifically for that!

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample for strict Oauth2 and not service account authorization.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages':['geochart'],
        });
        function drawRegionsMap(mapData) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);

            var options = {};

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>google analytics data API realtime Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = appConfig.CLIENT_ID
    const API_KEY = appConfig.API_KEY

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

    const PROPERTY_ID = appConfig.PROPERTY_ID

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
                handleAuthClick()
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token.access_token);
            await getRealTime();
        };

        if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
            // get saved access token.
            access_token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
            // set it in the client
            gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: access_token });
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            //document.getElementById('content').innerText = "Reading from local storage: " + token.access_token
            getRealTime();
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';

        } else if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            // save the access token to localstorage to prevent loss during a refresh
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token.access_token);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            // Clear the access token from the client and the local storage.
            gapi.client.setToken('');
            localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Realtime reports show events and usage data for the periods of time ranging
     * from the present moment to 30 minutes ago (up to 60 minutes for Google Analytics
     * 360 properties) and can be used for applications such as live counters of visitors
     * on your website.
     */
    async function getRealTime() {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await gapi.client.analyticsdata.properties.runRealtimeReport({
                'property': 'properties/' + PROPERTY_ID,
                dimensions: [{ name: 'country', },],
                metrics: [{ name: 'activeUsers', },],
            });
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
            return;
        }
        const data = response.result;

        if (!data) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'Error requesting profile.';
            return;
        }

        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

        const rows = data.rows
        if (!rows) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No data ' + jsonString;
            return;
        }

        const formattedData = [];

        // Add the header row
        formattedData.push(['city', 'activeUsers']);

        // Process each data item
        for (const row of rows) {
            const city = row.dimensionValues[0].value;
            const activeUsers = parseInt(row.metricValues[0].value);

            // Add the formatted data row
            formattedData.push([city, activeUsers]);
        }


        drawRegionsMap(formattedData)
        //document.getElementById('content').innerText = jsonString
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have any issues.